# Issues with ajax contact form inside wordpress theme

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, validation

I am facing a problem with a site I have been asked to look into. The form in this page:

http://www.emerygrid.ru/en/service/product-samples/

Does not seem to work at all... The form does not even validate, let alone send an email!

It's supposed to first validate (there is error handling), then send an email (set in WP options)

I do not have much info on details, but if someone is willing to point me in the right direction, I am more than happy to provide information.
Keep in mind that I am not very strong with Jquery, so you have to make it really simple for me....

Thanks people!

Comment: This isn't really appropriate. It's pretty much, doing your job. If you have problems with sections or understanding the code, please ask and people will be ore than willing to help. Don't just hope someone will fix it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing Happens when you click submit because in your js you are calling this

`$(".comment_form, .contact_form").submit(function(event)` and you have used `event.preventDefault();` , therefore the form does not show default behavior. Check the console there is an error in you js. It says

**TypeError: $(...).block is not a function.**

you need to fix these errors first.

This is the js which is handling your form.

```
 if($(".contact_form").length)
            $(".contact_form")[0].reset();
        if($(".comment_form").length)
            $(".comment_form")[0].reset();
        $(".comment_form, .contact_form").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serializeArray();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#"+id+" .block").block({
                message: false,
                overlayCSS: {
                    opacity:'0.3',
                    "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: config.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(json){
                    //$("#"+id+" [name='submit'], #"+id+" [name='name'], #"+id+" [name='contact_name'], #"+id+" [name='telephone'], #"+id+" [name='email'], #"+id+" [name='products']").qtip('destroy');
                    if(typeof(json.isOk)!="undefined" && json.isOk)
                    {
                        if(typeof(json.submit_message)!="undefined" && json.submit_message!="")
                        {
                            $("#"+id+" [name='submit']").qtip(
                            {
                                style: {
                                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-success'
                                },
                                content: { 
                                    text: json.submit_message 
                                },
                                position: { 
                                    my: "right center",
                                    at: "left center" 
                                }
                            }).qtip('show');
                            //close tooltip after 5 sec
                            /*setTimeout(function(){
                                $("#"+id+" [name='submit']").qtip("api").hide();
                            }, 5000);*/
                            if(id=="comment_form" && typeof(json.html)!="undefined")
                            {
                                $(".comments").html(json.html);
                                $("#comment_form [name='comment_parent_id']").val(0);
                                if(typeof(json.comment_id)!="undefined")
                                {
                                    var offset = $("#comment-" + json.comment_id).offset();
                                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: offset.top-10}, 400);
                                    if(typeof(json.change_url)!="undefined" && $.param.fragment()!=json.change_url.replace("#", ""))
                                        $("#comment_form [name='prevent_scroll']").val(1);
                                }
                                if(typeof(json.change_url)!="undefined" && $.param.fragment()!=json.change_url.replace("#", ""))
                                    $.bbq.pushState(json.change_url);
                                    //window.location.href = json.change_url;
                            }
                            $("#"+id)[0].reset();
                            $("#cancel_comment").css("display", "none");
                            $(".contact_form [name='department']").val("");
                            $(".contact_form .tabs_box_navigation_selected>span").text("Select department");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You are right @Adeel ... the default behavior is indeed disabled due to the function that validates the input. I came across another post that suggested I replace "$" with "jQuery" as a way to get rid of "not a function" errors. And it worked... now I can move on with the rest of the form errors (plenty of them, mostly typos etc...)

Comment: Ok. If it did help mark it as checked.